# Set conditional breakpoint in lldb for integer variable

Tags: lldb, conditional-breakpoint

ALL,

I'm trying to debug a failure in the unit test.

The code is running a loop of 1000 iterations and the failure occur in the step 140.

I'm on OSX and so using lldb.

I tried to do:

```
break set -f textctrltest.cpp -l 681 -c i == 139
```

but the code still stopped at the line with the i == 1.

Unfortunately it looks like all similar question refer to the string conditional breakpoint and no basic integer check.

Could someone please explain how to do that properly?

TIA!!

Answer (score 0):

The lldb command line is space delimited.  So the actual condition text your command set when doing:

```
break set -f textctrltest.cpp -l 681 -c i == 139
```

was just `i`, and then the command had two arguments, `==` and `139`.

If you make this mistake in a recent lldb, the command will generate the error:

```
(lldb) break set -f textctrltest.cpp -l 681 -c i == 139
error: 'breakpoint set' doesn't take any arguments.
```

though in older lldb's the command parser had a bug where it just ignored extra arguments, which is probably why you didn't notice this.

The correct command is:

```
(lldb) break set -f textctrltest.cpp -l 681 -c "i == 139"
Breakpoint 1: no locations (pending).
```

You can also verify that this worked with `break list`, which lists the condition among other details:

```
(lldb) break list 1
1: file = 'textctrltest.cpp', line = 681, exact_match = 0, locations = 0 (pending)
Condition: i == 139
```

Comment: Understood, thx. As my old teacher said - we are punished by using spaces... ;-)